# Take images from a directory, crop and save all images in the directory

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to crop high-resolution images to something more manageable.  I am trying to read in a directory rather than individual images and save the new cropped images in another directory. I would like to make all the output images as .png as I have in my code.

```
import cv2

path = './imgs2/P5.png'
img= cv2.imread (path)
imgcropped = img [1:400, 1:400]
cv2.imwrite ('./imgs/P5-cropped', imgcropped)
```

Any help with this problem is appreciated.

Comment: You don't need any Python for that btw, you can just use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal. First create the output directory `mkdir OUTPUT` then `magick mogrify -crop 400x400+0+0 -path OUTPUT *png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I use in this case:

```
import os
import cv2

path = 'path/to/image/dir/'
dest_path = 'path/to/destination/'

for f in os.listdir(path):
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, f))
    imgcropped = image[1:400, 1:400]
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dest_path, f), imgcropped)
```

Assuming that:

- the images in `path` are already .png
- `path` contains only the images you want to convert

`os.listdir` will give you the names of the files inside your origin dir (including extension), which you can use in `imwrite` to save the image in your destination dir with the same filename.